# Is there a way for Vite to automatically import module(s) that are commonly used?

Tags: reactjs, vite

Consider that I have some `Box` React component I use all over the place. Is there a way that this type can be inferred app-wide?  I want to be able to write

```
// no imports

export function Banner() {
  return <Box>My site</Box>
}
```

which of course won't work by default because it doesn't know what `Box` is. Can this be configured to just default to some import path, say `import { Box } from '@/platformStuff'`. Of course, ideally the resulting js bundle doesn't include the module if I *don't* use it in my app, but by definition, this is stuff that I expect to appear frequently throughout the app, so treeshaking isn't likely to kick it out of the bundle anyway, so it's fine if there are a bunch of 'hidden imports'.

Comment: Most IDE's have a option to automatically add imports, you should try that

Comment: That's of course what I do, but there are times where there are multiple Box components available too. Plus I'd like to get rid of those extra couple clicks per file, if possible.

Comment: It's just a keypress for me and if there are options I can select one with my arrow keys. Exactly because of the potential ambiguity I'd suggest explicitly importing the one you want

Comment: I appreciate the opinion, but it's really not the question I'm asking here

Comment: You really don't want to implicitly import things

Comment: Why do you believe that?

Comment: There is ambiguity when there are different objects with the same name, your IDE won't understand the imports so you are giving up autocomplete, your linters won't understand it so you will give up linting. Any other programmers (including your future self) looking at your code will have no idea where those objects come from.

Comment: The IDE doesn't exist in a bubble; if I supply some alias like `import { Box } from '@myStuff'`, "myStuff" isn't defined in the file, but is instead aware of surrounding context. Same with linters, which have config files.  I don't know how all the interdependencies work, but there are often ways to provide such context to ancillary tooling. 

If you've ever worked at a larger company, there are often a number standard constructs, which will be known to all devs. Worst case, you f12 or mouse over the type and see what it is, and ctrl+shift+f to find out how it's being imported.

Comment: Yea all those things only work if your IDE understands where the import comes from. All these tools have configs that could potentially allow customizing the import process but its' completely different for every linting tool. You need to spend probably hours debugging every single tool you use for the benefit of saving a single mouse click

Comment: Plus of course many who don't even support this, which you wouldn't be able to use at all